# PayPal using MVC issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am trying to set up a simple payment using PayPal and MVC, right now I have code which accepts an ID from the database on items you can purchase.

I have managed to find code which takes me to this screen:

[image]

I have some code which after you click "Continue" PayPal will return to and call, but the only thing I have in that bit of code is this:

```
public ActionResult PayPalExpressCheckoutAuthorisedSuccess(string token, string PayerID)
{

    return RedirectToAction("GivePurchasedItemsToUse");
}
```

I can see they have given me the token and payer id, but I am unsure where to go from here, in the PayPalExpressCheckourAuthorisedSuccess method, do I send something back to PayPal? Nothing yet has been displayed on any of the two PayPal accounts I am using.

The tutorial I followed was: http://rituranjangupta.blogspot.nl/2012/10/paypal-with-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood the state of where you are, which is *after* a user has **"approved*"** a Paypal Payment (where Paypal redirects back to your `RETURNURL`), you will need to "complete" the transaction.

- `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` - (optional) if you want to obtain details e.g. Paypal shipping address
- `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`  - this is the actual step that *completes* the transaction

Extensive Reference: [Paypal Developer -> Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/)

---

**approved*

*TIP: Don't misinterpret "approved" as "payment" - all it really means is that the user has approved a Paypal payment for you to use (e.g. user has agreed to pay some amount, chosen what funding source, shipping, etc.) - you still need to "finalize" things*

Hth..